# WinRT: downloading file

Tags: windows-runtime

I want to download file from server and show the progress of loading. How may I do this?

For downloading I use this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
Stream response = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
```

But I don't know how to get size of downloading file and don't know how much it was downloaded
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

There is StatusCode property in response object, you can analyze this property whether you get OK or PartialContent. 
You can also watch the following links for further details:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/f27c385a-e783-4062-a0b8-e21bf1704f95

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781241.aspx

Comment: it's useless for me. I need to know size when file is downloading. (not after it loads and went back to the main stream)

Comment: Sometimes it's possible, but sometimes header will have null instead of size long? length = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

Comment: i know how find full size.but  GetAsync - is async operation. and result i will get only after it will finish. and I want to know size of downloaded content step by step.

Comment: byte[] result = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
long portionSize = result.Length; You will get your file by parts and it's discrete process.

Comment: "Your problem is a good candidate for using the HttpClient handler pipeline.  You can make a new class (probably derived from  MessageProcessingHandler) that can examine the bytes going to and from your service and can track your progress.   For more information on handlers, please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781241.aspx"